# Theta join in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a theta join in SAS which need to be translate into Hive.

SAS:

```
select a.id,b.name from employee a 
left outer join company b 
on ( a.id=b.id and a.joindate>=b.joindate and a.releasedate < b.releasedate)
```

Since this is not inner join, I am not getting proper results if I add non equi-join in the where condition (all non matched records from left table are missing).

Tried below in Hive:

```
select a.id,b.name from employee a 
left outer join company b 
on ( a.id=b.id) 
where a.joindate>=b.joindate and a.releasedate < b.releasedate
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just as you may have realized, `left join` keeps all the items from the Preserved Row Table (employee), whereas your `where` filters out those items if `a.joindate<b.joindate or a.releasedate >= b.releasedate`.

Those `on` conditions are *logically* interpreted as:

> 1. For each item `li` from the left table, whenever an item `ri` from the right table is found to meet the `on` conditions, make a new item `ni` whose columns values are the combination of `li` and `ri`. Then put `ni` in the result set. This may duplicate rows from the left table.
> 2. If `li` fails to find a match, make one copy of it, fill the right columns with nulls. Put this item in the result set too.

So we can emulate this behavior by:

> 1. Loosen the `on` conditions by keeping just equality conditions within the `on` clause;
> 2. Filter out extra rows indroduced by the loosened `on` conditions, i.e., rows that fail to meet conditions other than equality conditions.

The resultant query may look like this:

```sql
select 
    a.id,
    b.name
from employee a 
left outer join company b 
on (a.id=b.id)
where (b.id is null 
       or (a.joindate>=b.joindate and a.releasedate<b.releasedate))
```